# Inheritance is not supported, even with a custom OData Service Provider?

Tags: c#, inheritance, wcf-data-services, odata

**EDIT**: I went ahead and created a little project to demonstrate this issue (called RestfulTimesTest), available on [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=0E945D83357E9465&id=E945D83357E9465!108&sc=documents).

I built a custom `OData` Service Provider to provide queries and updates into a custom model, based on `Alex James'` excellent blog post on [Creating a Data Service Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/04/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-1-intro.aspx).

Consider the following 3 CLR classes: `ResidentialCustomer`, `Customer`, and `User`.  `ResidentialCustomer` extends `Customer`, `Customer` has a list of `User`s, and `User` has a reference back to `Customer`.

The issue I'm having is that the metadata can include `ResidentialCustomer` or the association between `Customer` and `User`, but not both.  If I include both, I get the following error when trying to display or access the metadata via the `DataService`:

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceProviderWrapper.GetResourceAssociationSet(ResourceSetWrapper resourceSet, ResourceType resourceType, ResourceProperty resourceProperty)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.MetadataManager.GetAndValidateResourceAssociationSet(ResourceSetWrapper resourceSet, ResourceType resourceType, ResourceProperty navigationProperty)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.MetadataManager.PopulateAssociationsForSetAndType(ResourceSetWrapper resourceSet, ResourceType resourceType)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.MetadataManager.PopulateAssociationsForSet(ResourceSetWrapper resourceSet)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.MetadataManager..ctor(DataServiceProviderWrapper provider, IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.GenerateMetadata(MetadataEdmSchemaVersion metadataEdmSchemaVersion, IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceProviderWrapper.WriteMetadataDocument(MetadataSerializer serializer, XmlWriter writer, IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.Serializers.MetadataSerializer.WriteRequest(IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.ResponseBodyWriter.Write(Stream stream)}
```

The issue is happening when the `GetResourceAssociationSet` method in the class that implements `IDataServiceMetadataProvider` (see more details below) is called with a `ResourceSet` of a different type (`ResidentialCustomer`) than the passed in `ResourceType` (`Customer`):

```
public ResourceAssociationSet GetResourceAssociationSet(ResourceSet resourceSet, ResourceType resourceType, ResourceProperty resourceProperty) 
{ 
    return resourceProperty.CustomState as ResourceAssociationSet; 
}
```

This causes a failure in the .net library class method `ResourceAssociationSet.GetResourceAssociationSetEnd`, where it fails to find a `ResourceAssociationSetEnd`, subsequently causing the null reference exception.

The class that implements `IServiceProvider` (see more details below) sets up the metadata.  It sets up the association between `Customer` and `User` as follows:

```
        ResourceAssociationSet customerUserListSet = new ResourceAssociationSet(
            "CustomerUserList",
            new ResourceAssociationSetEnd(
                customerSet,
                customer,
                customerUserList
            ),
            new ResourceAssociationSetEnd(
                userSet,
                user,
                userCustomer
            )
        );
        customerUserList.CustomState = customerUserListSet;
        userCustomer.CustomState = customerUserListSet;
        metadata.AddAssociationSet(customerUserListSet);
```

A `ResidentialCustomer` should have access to its list of `User`s just like a `Customer`.  An object that inherits another should be able to use the base associations.  I do not believe the solution is to add another association between `ResidentialCustomer` and `User`, and trying to do so leads to property conflicts or undefined properties.  **What piece am I missing for setting up associations between objects that are inherited by other objects?**

**Additional Details:**
The associated classes for the custom provider are as follows:

An interface for `DataContext` classes such as:

```
public interface IODataContext
{
    IQueryable GetQueryable(ResourceSet set); 
    object CreateResource(ResourceType resourceType);
    void AddResource(ResourceType resourceType, object resource);
    void DeleteResource(object resource);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

A class to implement `IDataServiceMetadataProvider` such as:

```
public class ODataServiceMetadataProvider : IDataServiceMetadataProvider
{
    private Dictionary<string, ResourceType> resourceTypes = new Dictionary<string, ResourceType>();
    private Dictionary<string, ResourceSet> resourceSets = new Dictionary<string, ResourceSet>();
    private List<ResourceAssociationSet> _associationSets = new List<ResourceAssociationSet>(); 

    public string ContainerName
    {
        get { return "MyDataContext"; }
    }

     public string ContainerNamespace
     {
         get { return "MyNamespace"; }
     }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceSet> ResourceSets
    {
         get { return this.resourceSets.Values; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ServiceOperation> ServiceOperations
    {
        get { yield break; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceType> Types
    {
        get { return this.resourceTypes.Values; }
    }

    public bool TryResolveResourceSet(string name, out ResourceSet resourceSet)
    {
        return resourceSets.TryGetValue(name, out resourceSet);
    }

    public bool TryResolveResourceType(string name, out ResourceType resourceType)
    {
        return resourceTypes.TryGetValue(name, out resourceType);
    }

    public bool TryResolveServiceOperation(string name, out ServiceOperation serviceOperation)
    {
        serviceOperation = null;
        return false;
    }

    public void AddResourceType(ResourceType type)
    {
        type.SetReadOnly();
        resourceTypes.Add(type.FullName, type);
    }

    public void AddResourceSet(ResourceSet set)
    {
        set.SetReadOnly();
        resourceSets.Add(set.Name, set);
    }

    public bool HasDerivedTypes(ResourceType resourceType)
    {
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(ResidentialCustomer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceType> GetDerivedTypes(ResourceType resourceType)
    {
        List<ResourceType> derivedResourceTypes = new List<ResourceType>();
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(ResidentialCustomer))
        {
            foreach (ResourceType resource in Types)
            {
                if (resource.InstanceType == typeof(Customer))
                {
                    derivedResourceTypes.Add(resource);
                }
            }
        }
        return derivedResourceTypes;
    }

    public void AddAssociationSet(ResourceAssociationSet associationSet) 
    {
        _associationSets.Add(associationSet); 
    }

    public ResourceAssociationSet GetResourceAssociationSet(ResourceSet resourceSet, ResourceType resourceType, ResourceProperty resourceProperty)
    {
        return resourceProperty.CustomState as ResourceAssociationSet;
    }

    public ODataServiceMetadataProvider() { }
}
```

A class to implement `IDataServiceQueryProvider` such as:

```
public class ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> : IDataServiceQueryProvider where T : IODataContext
{
    T _currentDataSource;
    IDataServiceMetadataProvider _metadata;

    public object CurrentDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentDataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentDataSource = (T)value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsNullPropagationRequired
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public object GetOpenPropertyValue(object target, string propertyName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetOpenPropertyValues(object target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetPropertyValue(object target, ResourceProperty resourceProperty)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable GetQueryRootForResourceSet(ResourceSet resourceSet)
    {
        return _currentDataSource.GetQueryable(resourceSet);
    }

    public ResourceType GetResourceType(object target)
    {
        Type type = target.GetType();
        return _metadata.Types.Single(t => t.InstanceType == type);
    }

    public object InvokeServiceOperation(ServiceOperation serviceOperation, object[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ODataServiceQueryProvider(IDataServiceMetadataProvider metadata)
    {
        _metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

A class to implement `IDataServiceUpdateProvider` such as:

```
public class ODataServiceUpdateProvider<T> : IDataServiceUpdateProvider where T : IODataContext
{
    private IDataServiceMetadataProvider _metadata;
    private ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> _query;
    private List<Action> _actions;

    public T GetContext()
    {
        return ((T)_query.CurrentDataSource);
    }

    public void SetConcurrencyValues(object resourceCookie, bool? checkForEquality, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> concurrencyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetReference(object targetResource, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        _actions.Add(() => ReallySetReference(targetResource, propertyName, propertyValue));
    }

    public void ReallySetReference(object targetResource, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        targetResource.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }

    public void AddReferenceToCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeAdded)
    {
        _actions.Add(() => ReallyAddReferenceToCollection(targetResource, propertyName, resourceToBeAdded));
    }

    public void ReallyAddReferenceToCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeAdded)
    {
        var collection = targetResource.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
        if (collection is IList)
        {
            (collection as IList).Add(resourceToBeAdded);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveReferenceFromCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeRemoved)
    {
        _actions.Add(() => ReallyRemoveReferenceFromCollection(targetResource, propertyName, resourceToBeRemoved));
    }

    public void ReallyRemoveReferenceFromCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeRemoved)
    {
        var collection = targetResource.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
        if (collection is IList)
        {
            (collection as IList).Remove(resourceToBeRemoved);
        }
    }

    public void ClearChanges()
    {
        _actions.Clear();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var a in _actions)
            a();
        GetContext().SaveChanges();
    }

    public object CreateResource(string containerName, string fullTypeName)
    {
        ResourceType type = null;
        if (_metadata.TryResolveResourceType(fullTypeName, out type))
        {
            var context = GetContext();
            var resource = context.CreateResource(type);
            _actions.Add(() => context.AddResource(type, resource));
            return resource;
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Type {0} not found", fullTypeName));
    }

    public void DeleteResource(object targetResource)
    {
        _actions.Add(() => GetContext().DeleteResource(targetResource));
    }

    public object GetResource(IQueryable query, string fullTypeName)
    {
        var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception("Resource not found");
        var resource = enumerator.Current;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            throw new Exception("Resource not uniquely identified");

        if (fullTypeName != null)
        {
            ResourceType type = null;
            if (!_metadata.TryResolveResourceType(fullTypeName, out type))
                throw new Exception("ResourceType not found");
            if (!type.InstanceType.IsAssignableFrom(resource.GetType()))
                throw new Exception("Unexpected resource type");
        }
        return resource;
   }

    public object ResetResource(object resource)
    {
        _actions.Add(() => ReallyResetResource(resource));
        return resource;
    }

    public void ReallyResetResource(object resource)
    {
        var clrType = resource.GetType();
        ResourceType resourceType = _metadata.Types.Single(t => t.InstanceType == clrType);
        var resetTemplate = GetContext().CreateResource(resourceType);

        foreach (var prop in resourceType.Properties
                 .Where(p => (p.Kind & ResourcePropertyKind.Key) != ResourcePropertyKind.Key))
        {
            var clrProp = clrType.GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == prop.Name);
            var defaultPropValue = clrProp.GetGetMethod().Invoke(resetTemplate, new object[] { });
            clrProp.GetSetMethod().Invoke(resource, new object[] { defaultPropValue });
        }
    }

    public object ResolveResource(object resource)
    {
        return resource;
    }

    public object GetValue(object targetResource, string propertyName)
    {
        var value = targetResource.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == propertyName).GetGetMethod().Invoke(targetResource, new object[] { });
        return value;
    }

    public void SetValue(object targetResource, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        targetResource.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == propertyName).GetSetMethod().Invoke(targetResource, new[] { propertyValue });
     }

     public ODataServiceUpdateProvider(IDataServiceMetadataProvider metadata, ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> query)
     {
         _metadata = metadata;
         _query = query;
         _actions = new List<Action>();
    }
}
```

A class to implement `IServiceProvider` such as:

```
public class ODataService<T> : DataService<T>, IServiceProvider where T : IODataContext
{
    private ODataServiceMetadataProvider _metadata;
    private ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> _query;
    private ODataServiceUpdateProvider<T> _updater;

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == typeof(IDataServiceMetadataProvider))
        {
            return _metadata;
        }
        else if (serviceType == typeof(IDataServiceQueryProvider))
        {
            return _query;
        }
        else if (serviceType == typeof(IDataServiceUpdateProvider))
        {
            return _updater;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ODataServiceMetadataProvider GetMetadataProvider(Type dataSourceType)
    {
        ODataServiceMetadataProvider metadata = new ODataServiceMetadataProvider();
        ResourceType customer = new ResourceType(
            typeof(Customer),
            ResourceTypeKind.EntityType,
            null,
            "MyNamespace",
            "Customer",
            false
        );
        ResourceProperty customerCustomerID = new ResourceProperty(
            "CustomerID",
            ResourcePropertyKind.Key |
            ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive,
            ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(Guid))
        );
        customer.AddProperty(customerCustomerID);
        ResourceProperty customerCustomerName = new ResourceProperty(
            "CustomerName",
            ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive,
            ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(string))
        );
        customer.AddProperty(customerCustomerName);
        ResourceType residentialCustomer = new ResourceType(
            typeof(ResidentialCustomer),
            ResourceTypeKind.EntityType,
            customer,
            "MyNamespace",
            "ResidentialCustomer",
            false
        );
        ResourceType user = new ResourceType(
            typeof(User),
            ResourceTypeKind.EntityType,
            null,
            "MyNamespace",
            "User",
            false
        );
        ResourceProperty userUserID = new ResourceProperty(
            "UserID",
            ResourcePropertyKind.Key |
            ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive,
            ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(Guid))
        );
        user.AddProperty(userUserID);
        ResourceProperty userCustomerID = new ResourceProperty(
            "CustomerID",
            ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive,
            ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(Guid))
        );
        user.AddProperty(userCustomerID);
        ResourceProperty userEmailAddress = new ResourceProperty(
            "EmailAddress",
            ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive,
            ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(string))
        );
        user.AddProperty(userEmailAddress);

        var customerSet = new ResourceSet("Customers", customer);
        var residentialCustomerSet = new ResourceSet("ResidentialCustomers", residentialCustomer);
        var userSet = new ResourceSet("Users", user);

        var userCustomer = new ResourceProperty(
            "Customer",
            ResourcePropertyKind.ResourceReference,
            customer
        );
        user.AddProperty(userCustomer);

        var customerUserList = new ResourceProperty(
            "UserList",
            ResourcePropertyKind.ResourceSetReference,
            user
        );
        customer.AddProperty(customerUserList);

        metadata.AddResourceType(customer);
        metadata.AddResourceSet(customerSet);
        metadata.AddResourceType(residentialCustomer);
        metadata.AddResourceSet(residentialCustomerSet);
        metadata.AddResourceType(user);
        metadata.AddResourceSet(userSet);

        ResourceAssociationSet customerUserListSet = new ResourceAssociationSet(
            "CustomerUserList",
            new ResourceAssociationSetEnd(
                customerSet,
                customer,
                customerUserList
            ),
            new ResourceAssociationSetEnd(
                userSet,
                user,
                userCustomer
            )
        );
        customerUserList.CustomState = customerUserListSet;
        userCustomer.CustomState = customerUserListSet;
        metadata.AddAssociationSet(customerUserListSet);

        return metadata;
    }

    public ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> GetQueryProvider(ODataServiceMetadataProvider metadata)
    {
        return new ODataServiceQueryProvider<T>(metadata);
    }

    public ODataServiceUpdateProvider<T> GetUpdateProvider(ODataServiceMetadataProvider metadata, ODataServiceQueryProvider<T> query)
    {
        return new ODataServiceUpdateProvider<T>(metadata, query);
    }

    public ODataService()
    {
        _metadata = GetMetadataProvider(typeof(T));
        _query = GetQueryProvider(_metadata);
        _updater = GetUpdateProvider(_metadata, _query);
    }
}
```

The `DataContext` class holds the CLR collections and wires up the service operations such as:

```
public partial class MyDataContext: IODataContext
{
    private List<Customer> _customers = null;
    public List<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_customers == null)
            {
                _customers = DataManager.GetCustomers);
            }
            return _customers;
        }
    }

    private List<ResidentialCustomer> _residentialCustomers = null;
    public List<ResidentialCustomer> ResidentialCustomers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_residentialCustomers == null)
            {
                _residentialCustomers = DataManager.GetResidentialCustomers();
            }
            return _residentialCustomers;
        }
    }

    private List<User> _users = null;
    public List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (_users == null)
            {
                _users = DataManager.GetUsers();
            }
            return _users;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable GetQueryable(ResourceSet set)
    {
        if (set.Name == "Customers") return Customers.AsQueryable();
        if (set.Name == "ResidentialCustomers") return ResidentialCustomers.AsQueryable();
        if (set.Name == "Users") return Users.AsQueryable();
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} not found", set.Name));
    }

    public object CreateResource(ResourceType resourceType)
    {
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(Customer))
        {
            return new Customer();
        }
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(ResidentialCustomer))
        {
            return new ResidentialCustomer();
        }
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(User))
        {
            return new User();
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} not found for creating.", resourceType.FullName));
    }

    public void AddResource(ResourceType resourceType, object resource)
    {
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(Customer))
        {
            Customer i = resource as Customer;
            if (i != null)
            {
                Customers.Add(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(ResidentialCustomer))
        {
            ResidentialCustomeri = resource as ResidentialCustomer;
            if (i != null)
            {
                ResidentialCustomers.Add(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (resourceType.InstanceType == typeof(User))
        {
            Useri = resource as User;
            if (i != null)
            {
                Users.Add(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} not found for adding.", resourceType.FullName));
    }

    public void DeleteResource(object resource)
    {
        if (resource.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
        {
            Customers.Remove(resource as Customer);
            return;
        }
        if (resource.GetType() == typeof(ResidentialCustomer))
        {
            ResidentialCustomers.Remove(resource as ResidentialCustomer);
            return;
        }
        if (resource.GetType() == typeof(User))
        {
            Users.Remove(resource as User);
            return;
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} not found for deletion.", resource.GetType().FullName));
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var item in Customers.Where(i => i.IsModified == true))
            item.Save();
        foreach (var item in ResidentialCustomers.Where(i => i.IsModified == true))
            item.Save();
        foreach (var item in Users.Where(i => i.IsModified == true))
            item.Save();
    }
}
```

The data service uses the custom data service class and the data context, such as:

```
public class MyDataService : ODataService<MyDataContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("ResidentialCustomers", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptProjectionRequests = true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further testing, it seems like there are currently two severe constraints on the metadata in order to expose it with a custom (or any?) `OData` Service Provider:

1) A `ResourceType` cannot extend another `ResourceType` (the `BaseType` for a `ResourceType` must be null).  To some extent, this constraint can be alleviated by replicating all properties of the base type into the extended type in the metadata.

2) A `ResourceType` or `ResourceSet` cannot be involved in an association, if its `InstanceType` extends another `InstanceType` referred to in the metadata, regardless of how the `ResourceType`s for each instance type are set up.  In other words in the example, if `ResidentialCustomer` extends `Customer` in the CLR model, I can't use a `ResourceType` or `ResourceSet` with an `InstanceType` of `ResidentialCustomer` in any association.  I don't know of any workaround to this, other than not providing these necessary associations via the `OData` Service Provider.

If I violate any of the above 2 constraints, I get a null reference exception in the .net library class method `ResourceAssociationSet.GetResourceAssociationSetEnd()`.

Are these constraints correct, or are there any examples to workaround these constraints or properly set up the metadata for these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I had also had a inheritance issue with an odata v1 service and i fixed it using an implicit operator:

```
class Example
{
    public class Object1
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object2
    {
        private readonly Object1 _object1;

        public Object2()
        {
            _object1 = new Object1();
        }

        public int Property1
        {
            get { return _object1.Property1; }
            set { _object1.Property1 = value; }
        }
        public string Property2
        {
            get { return _object1.Property2; }
            set { _object1.Property2 = value; }
        }

        public static implicit operator Object1(Object2 o)
        {
            return o._object1;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can cast a variable of type Object2 to Object1 and you can pass Object2 to all methods expecting an Object1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have 2 different sets of sets - one for Customers and one for ResidentialCustomer.

The problem from the model perspective is that given a user instance that belongs to Users set, which set does the navigation property 'Customer' refer to - it can refer to customer set from Customers or ResidentialCustomer.

The question is why do you want to have 2 sets for customers and residential customers? If you want to access residentialCustomers from customers set, you can always query /Customers/Namespace.ResidentialCustomer and that will give you all the residential customers from the Customers set.

If you really want to have 2 different sets for customer and residentialcustomer, then have a base class (CustomerBase) which has all the common properties between the 2 types and then define Users navigation property on both Customer and ResidentialCustomer, with different association set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Pratik.  I need a separate set of `ResidentialCustomers` from `Customers` since only some `Customers` are `ResidentialCustomers` and `ResidentialCustomer` has additional data properties.  I tried adding multiple associations, but that would require creating `ResidentialCustomer.ResidentialUserList`, `Customer.UserList`, `User.Customer`, and `User.ResidentialCustomer`, which would destroy the utility of the underlying data model.  It just seems the `OData` model doesn't support inheritance very well in general.